# vlc : how to specify playlist on command line

Tags: vlc

The playlist is a plain text file of filenames

I have tried :

```
 cvlc --playlist playlist
 cvlc -playlist playlist
```

And each of those with `playlist=playlist`.

I have renamed the playlist to `playlist.m3u`

I have tried :

```
 vlc --longhelp | grep playlist
```

And see nothing but options for a running playlist.

My web searches have lots on how to use the GUI for a playlist but not for the commandline.

This used to work but I haven't used VLC for a while.

Comment: @Rinzwind Woops. I had started a question about routing that in writing out I realized what was wrong!  Then later I re-used the form. Sorry. Thanks for fixing.

Comment: There have an upvote :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The playlist is a plain text file of filenames

It needs to be a .m3u list and it will look like this example:

```
# This is a comment
/music/opeth/white cluster.mp3
/music/moonlapse vertigo.mp3
http://ccmixter.org/a/song.mp3
/video/mononoke.avi
```

and you play them without any parameters like:

```
vlc playlist.m3u
```

The only issue I can see here is that the files are not correct in your file.

Comment: My error was that the filenames in my playlist were not full physical paths but the names in the same directory as the playlist.

Comment: ah! would have been nice if vlc alerted about it :P

Comment: Good point. One of my playlists had errors in the filename and VLC did complain about that so... There may have been something else wrong that coincidentally changed. When I posted the question VLC seemed to simply stall.

Comment: note to self: it must end in m3u (not txt!)